# Strange C# behaviour on one line

Tags: c#-4.0

I am experiencing some problems with a line of C# code.
I'm trying to get the end customer amount of a price in our database. It is a nullable decimal so if it isn't filled in, I use 0.

Could someone look at this line of code and give me an explanation to why this doesn't work?

This is the specific line:

```
Decimal totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.HasValue ? requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.Value : 0;
```

The problem is that for some prices, the totalPrice is 0 even when the EndCustomerAmount has a value.

If I debug the code and I execute the if statement in the immediate window, it returns the correct value. Even when I assign the value in the immediate window the totalPrice variable holds the correct amount.

I have tried following lines to solve the problem but with no luck:

```
Decimal totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount ?? 0;
```

And this:

```
Decimal totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount ?? 0m;
```

And this:

```
Decimal totalPrice = 0
totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.HasValue ? requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.Value : 0;
```

What does seem to work is this:

```
Decimal totalPrice = 0
if(requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.HasValue)
    totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount
```

Or this:

```
Decimal? totalPrice = requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.HasValue ? requestedPrice.EndCustomerAmount.Value : 0;
```

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you please provide a short but complete reproduction of this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't, it would take ma a lot of time to give you the code. I found out that the code is actually working. It seems to be some kind of visual studio issue where visual studio is not showing the correct value... The result of the code actually contains the right price after I resolved another issue. In debug it keeps showing the wrong price though... (FYI, I use Visual Studio 2010 SP1)

Comment: In that case, you could create at least some screenshots illustrating the problem.

Comment: My coleague was able to reproduce the problem with some test code. He will post it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog post explaining the debugger issues, including a response from Microsoft:

http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2011/03/31/misreporting-of-variable-values-when-debugging-x64-code-with-the.aspx

Tl;dr: It's an issue with the ?? and ?: operators on nullable struct types larger than 64 bits (Decimal, Guid, ...) in the 64 bit CLR JIT where their value is not updated until the next statement. It has been fixed in VS2012.

If you're interested in a simplistic reproduction, just run this in 64x debug in VS2010:

```
Decimal? foo = 10.5m;
var result = foo.HasValue ? foo.Value : 0;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Put your breakpoint on the Console.Writeline line. Hover over result and see the 0. If we defined and assigned a value to result earlier, it would still show the old value. When using result in watches of immediate window execution it will still use the old value. Moving to the next line, you'll see the value updates.